# Simplemembership webpages_UsersInRoles code first FK error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement the SimpleMembership entities so I can control some aspects of it, Here are the classes I created:

```
 [Table("webpages_Roles")]
 public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        UsersInRoles = new List<UsersInRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<Membership> Members { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public ICollection<UsersInRole> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
}
[Table("webpages_UsersInRoles")]
public class UsersInRole
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Column("RoleId"), InverseProperty("UsersInRoles")]
    public Role Roles { get; set; }

    [Column("UserId"), InverseProperty("UsersInRoles")]
    public Membership Members { get; set; }



}
 [Table("webpages_Membership")]
public class Membership
{
    public Membership()
    {
        //Roles = new List<Role>();
        OAuthMemberships = new List<OAuthMembership>();
        UsersInRoles = new List<UsersInRole>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ICollection<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ICollection<UsersInRole> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

Now as soon as I try to insert a new user, it is inserted correctly on the tables userProfile and webpages_Membership but as soon as the application tries to assign a role to the user an exception is thrown

*The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles_dbo.webpages_Membership_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "PCSPI", table "dbo.webpages_Membership", column 'UserId'.
The statement has been terminated.*

I tried to insert it manually with sql server and it inserts but as soon as I try to do it on my application the exception is thrown.

What am I doing wrong? isnt the model well defined?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reading comments. I think you got that schema from: http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model

And one of the comment below says that the schema is incorrect and gives correct schema that defo works as I'm using it. I don't want to repeat that here. Go to the above mentioned site and check again. (Comment by Senad Karic)

P.S. Don't worry, I did the same the first time I used it :)

Comment: the link appears to be broken.

Comment: I have contacted the author of the page, and unfortunately the content was lost and the back up is missing. That means, the entire question should be deleted as it was cause by the mistake in the article that is deleted now.